# disable copy-on-write(COW) on some memory pages when doing fork()

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, copy-on-write

When a parent process forks a child process (under linux), I want to copy some of the memory pages in parent process to the address space of child process right at the beginning, which means, no need to wait for the copy-on-write(COW). Is there any mechanism support this? Thanks:-)

Comment: Hm, I don't understand the question, maybe you can clarify. Do you expect to have some shared memory between parent in child? Otherwise, if the parent has set up the memory properly (i.e., filled a region with data) before the fork, then after the fork the child can find that data in the same place (in it's own address space).

Comment: Premature optimization considered harmful, and premature pessimization even moreso. Unless you can provide a reason for what you're trying to do, I think you're making a huge mistake, and probably don't understand COW.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any interface for this, but you always do it manually, either with a `memcpy` or just by touching the pages in question (e.g., read the first word, then write it back). Be sure to mark the page as `volatile`.

Comment: +1, but no need to turn off optimization, marking the memory as `volatile` would do.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [`clone`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) system call. The most relevant option is `CLONE_VM`. It's important to realize the copy-on-write behavior of pages after a fork is purely an optimization. I can't foresee any situation where this can be a problem, except perhaps where you wish to incur all potentially "lazy" performance penalties due to page duplication up front. Even for these, you may be overzealous in wishing to touch every writable page, as you'll be increasing physical memory use for every process forked from the original.

Comment: Virtual address space is already used, even with COW. CLONE_VM would create tasks with all shared memory (it's one of the flags used by threads).

Comment: @ninjalj: Correct in both cases. I wrote this last night, my statement regarding virtual memory usage is incorrect.